# I'm using tabs and I want to use next/previous buttons to switch between tabs

Tags: html

I tried to use #href on my buttons in order to get them to change to another tab but all it ends up doing is adding #name in the url. How can I make it so my next and previous buttons change to the respective tab?

```
<div class="card text-left">
  <div class="card-header bg-danger">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-background-color="red">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" style="color:white" href="#generalinfo">General Info</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" style="color:white" href="#companyinfo">Company Info</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" style="color:white" href="#socialmedia">Social Media</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="generalinfo" role="tabpanel">
                <form action="" id="generalInfo">
                    <a href="#companyinfo" class="btn btn-danger mt-3 float-right">Next</a>
                </form>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane" id="companyinfo" role="tabpanel">
                <form action="" id="companyInfo">
                   <a href="#generalinfo" class="btn btn-danger mt-3">Back</a>
                   <a href="#socialmedia" class="btn btn-danger mt-3 float-right">Next</a>
                </form>
    </div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: where is your javascript?

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE] including CSS and Javascript